# How can I get back the naming box for Checkpoints in Windows Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v

When creating a checkpoint, Hyper-V asks for a name. In that dialog is a checkbox that allows auto-naming. Unfortunately I checked this and now I can only rename checkpoints afterwards but not name them during creation.

Anyone knows where I can set this flag back?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a checkpoint name consists of the VM name it belongs to and a time stamp. It might be a good idea to improve the naming system or create yours from scratch.

From my personal experience, it’s always nice to have a reason why a checkpoint was taken, along with a time stamp in the checkpoint name. It might sound obvious or like something you don’t have to pay attention to, but it can save your life. On the other hand, a possible solution in your case could be the modification the VM name and a recreation of a Checkpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but the question was not about wy names are good but about bringing back the dialog box, that allows setting the name.